# HSQLDB inserting datetime format for SQL Server throws exception

Tags: sql-server, hsqldb

I am trying to run unit tests for my SQL Server query. Query is simply inserting date to the table. I tried two different formats but didn't work:

```
parameters.addValue(STUDY_DATE, getDate(studyEvent.getStudy().getStudyDate()));
```

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(getDate(studyEvent.getStudy().getStudyDate()).getTimeInMillis());
parameters.addValue(STUDY_DATE, timestamp);
```

And this is `getDate()` method that returns Calendar object:

```
private Calendar getDate(long time) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
    return calendar;
}
```

I am not sure if the problem is that SQL Server's datetime format issue or hsqldb issue. Here is my hsqldb create table:

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX MSS TRUE;

DROP TABLE event_study IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE event_study
(
    STUDY_ID INT,
    STUDY_DATE DATE
)
```

Is my hsqldb setup wrong? or should I use different datetime format for SQL Server?

Error I am getting is:

> data exception: invalid datetime format; nested exception is java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: invalid datetime format

and SQL query that I am running is:

```
INSERT INTO event_study(study_id, study_date)
            SELECT x.*
            FROM (VALUES(:study_id, :study_date))
            AS x(study_id, study_date)
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM event_study s WHERE s.study_id = x.study_id)
```

Comment: What is the error you get? We would also need to see the code that actually runs the INSERT statement (e.g. how the `PreparedStatement` is created and executed))

Comment: Why aren't you using `SqlParameter` instances with specific database types (e.g.: `Types.DATE`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not using strings for dates, this is not actually a formatting issue, but a Java type issue. With your table definition, `DATE` does not have time information. You can create and use a `java.sql.Date` object for the parameter value. If you want a datetime column, which includes information on time of the day, then use `TIMESTAMP` in your table definition and a `java.sql.Timestamp` for the parameter value.

In either case, you cannot use a Calendar object as parameter value.

Comment: I am little curious why this works with Oracle SQL setup..

Comment: I created `Timestamp` object in parameter and change `DATE` to `DATETIME` it works.

Comment: Different JDBC drivers may allow different additional types, such as Calendar. With Oracle, DATE is actually an alias for a kind o TIMESTAMP. Using Timestamp together with TIMESTAMP ( DATETIME is an alias for SQL TIMESTAMP) should work with most database engines.